# What does D.Va say in Korean when respawning?

Tags: overwatch

One of the lines D.Va says after she respawns is in Korean. Does anybody know what it is and to what it translates in English?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[She says "Annoying"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AY7cXDjJxaA&t=7m17s)  (Click for a youtube video)

She also may say "I play to win" but that's her tag line and not necessarily her respawn line

Comment: Where in the video does she say it, exactly? That's a long video to watch for a single word.

Comment: @Fluttershy When you click it goes to the exact point she says it ... check the url "=7m17s"

Comment: Oh, okay. For some reason, it didn't do that on my phone. Weird.

Comment: How is it in Korean?

Comment: @donut I believe it's because of her Nationality --> http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/D.Va

Comment: @ИвоНедев I mean how do you write it in Korean.

Comment: I think she has a voice line where she says "I play to win" in Korean as well, so that might be uttered after respawning on occasion.

Comment: @donut ah, probably something like 짜증나.

Comment: @DCShannon That's her tag line, she does say Annoying specifically on respawn.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. +1. Correct answer. I don't want to have to submit a separate answer just for something she might say occasionally, though. Suggest you add it for completeness.

Comment: For what it's worth, her "I play to win" line is 게임을 하면 이겨야지.

Comment: @ИвоНедев Is correct, she says "오, 짜증나".

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, she says 게임을 하면 이겨야지! Which also means, geim-eul hamyeon igyeoyaji! It's the "I play to win!" voiceline. I also completely translated it. It really means, "If you play a game, you have to win." She also says, "Annoying.." after a while of being killed a lot.